# E/zzf: Problem retrieving SafetyNet Token: 7:

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I have getting the error when i try to  register to the application. when i enter my phone number and register it goes to otp verification but did not get the otp. But it give me an error saying problem to get safety net token:7. Please help me through it. It is working before but now getting error.

I have add sha-1 and sha-256 as well in firebase setting.

my error

```
E/zzf: Problem retrieving SafetyNet Token: 7: 
E/FirebearCryptoHelper: Exception encountered during crypto setup:
Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero).
KeysetManager failed to initialize - unable to get Public key
E/RecaptchaActivity: Could not generate an encryption key for reCAPTCHA - cancelling flow.
W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 367
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 824349680
E/zzf: Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [An internal error has occurred. [ Failed to 
generate/retrieve public encryption key for reCAPTCHA flow. ]]- calling backend without app 
verification
```

Comment: Facing the same problem, Any solution?

Comment: Are you running the app on real device?

Comment: yes, the OTP thing never works

Comment: Try this one. May be you forget to do device verification. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67296754/android-security-keystoreexception-signature-mac-verification-failed/67325297?noredirect=1#comment119007404_67325297